# Self-referential structure in K&R

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

K&R(2nd) section 6.5 has two functions.

```
int main(void)
{
  struct tnode *root;
  char word[MAXWORD];

  root = NULL;
  while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)    
    if (isalpha(word[0]))                 
      root = addtree(root, word);         
  treeprint(root);
  return 0;
}

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w)
{
  int cond;

  if (p == NULL)               // a new word has arrived
    {                            
      p = talloc();            // make a new node 
      p->word = strdup(w);       
      p->count = 1;
      p->left = p->right = NULL;
    }
  else if ((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0)
    p->count++;               // repeated word
  else if (cond < 0)
    p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
  else
    p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
  return p;
}
```

I had no problem with understanding the flow of that program.
But I think `root = addtree(root, word);` in `main` is not efficient. `root` is first set to `NULL` and get an address when an adequate identifier is found. And once it has its address, additional assignment is useless. Am I right?
If so, I wrote my own version to avoid it. Can it fix the problem?

```
/* my edit */
int main(void)
{
    struct tnode *root;
    char word[MAXWORD];

    root = NULL;
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)   // ----------------------------------
        if (isalpha(word[0])) {             // |                                |
            root = addtree(root, word);     // |                                |
            break;                          // |          Changed part          |
    }                                       // |                                |
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)   // |                                |
        if (isalpha(word[0]))               // |                                |
            addtree(root, word);            // ----------------------------------
    treeprint(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not useless, because the called function can assign a new node pointer to the tree. The first call is a specific case of the general case where a `NULL` value node pointer can be assigned. Your proposed code appears to be *less* efficient than the original.

Comment: @WeatherVane Once root receive an address, then root is never changed. It can have only two value. `NULL` and an first given address. Isn't it? I think the called function always return the same address to root.

Comment: But it is recursive: it calls itself. More advanced tree inplementations will keep the tree balanced, which can mean changing the root.

Comment: @WeatherVane Then is the code for generic purpose? Are you saying 'Your proposed code appears to be *less* efficient than the original (**in general**)'?

Comment: Your code will fail to assign a value to `root` when `if (isalpha(word[0]))` is false.

Comment: @WeatherVane If  `if (isalpha(word[0]))` is false, then the test part of while is executed until  `while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF)` is false. My code may make no sense only if there is no any adequate identifier from input.

Comment: Either way, the first `while` is useless, since the `break` prevents the loop from iterating.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, you're right. I edited grouping, sorry. Anyway, do you agree with my first question on the post `But I think root = addtree(root, word); in main is not efficient ... Am I right?`? I think you say that's not true **in general**. Then, is it true within K&R program?

Comment: You have to balance the possible slight inefficiency of assigning a value to a variable which already has that value, against the complexity and readabilty of the code. From that point of view, your proposed change was less efficient, particularly as it introduced a bug. So no, I do not think your change was for the better.

Comment: Did you measure the performance gain from your code?  Was it detectable?  Was the increased code size beneficial?  My guess is that the answer to each question is No.  Worrying about that level of micro-inefficiency is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks to point that. I checked it out using clock() in time.h. The more I wrote in input, the more time was spent. So it was detectable. And yes, I agree with you `Was the increased code size beneficial?` my code is not beneficial. This is the same as Weather Vane's thought. I was just curious whether my code could change the point I said.